# Can't get type signature working for simple recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

Here is my code:

```
test :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
test []     = 0
test [x:xs] = x + test xs
```

Yet when I run it through ghci as `:l test`, I get this error:

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

```
test.hs:3:7:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for spew :: Num a => [a] -> a at test.hs:2:1
    In the pattern: x : xs
    In the pattern: [x : xs]
    In an equation for `spew': spew [x : xs] = x + spew xs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Try not to laugh :) it's my first attempt at haskell. Any help or explanations would be awesome.

PS: I know this could be easily done with a fold, but I'm trying to practice writing my own type signatures. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean

```
test :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
test []     = 0
test (x:xs) = x + test xs -- note round brackets
```

with round brackets.

`[x:xs]` is a list with one element, itself a list, whereas `(x:xs)` is a list with a first element `x` and tail `xs`.

If you type `length (1:[1,1,1])` you'll get 4, but if you type `length [1:[1,1,1]]` you'll get 1 - the only element is a list.

Comment: Gah!! I should've seen that! Thank you!

Comment: @AthanClark We all go through this feeling when we learn Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

You probably meant to match the list as a whole, not the first element of the list:

```
test (x:xs) = ...
```

If you do otherwise, the pattern has the inferred type `[[b]]`, so `a == [b]` according to `test`s signature, so `xs` must have type `[b]`, so `test xs` must have type `b` but also type `a` according to the signature of `test`, which would mean that `a == [a]`, which is a contradiction and leads to the unification error :)